# Modify and Concatenate in the same formula possible?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google spreadsheet with more than 1000 rows of data. Column A has unique ID numbers. Column B has video file names. If possible, I'd like to do the following **in a single formula**:

1. Enclose the base filename in square brackets (file extension should not be enclosed).
2. Concatenate columns A and B.
3. Output the result to Column C.

See screenshot below.

Is this possible without scripts and in a single formula? I tried the formula below but I get a parse error.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A:A&" ["&(SUBSTITUTE(B:B,.mp4,"]"&".mp4")))
```

*`SUBSTITUTE` above means I'm trying to substitute ".mp4" with the closing square bracket.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(A2:A&" ["&
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(.+)\.")&"]"&
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(\..+)")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(.+)\.", " [$1]."))
```

[image: 0]